# Why isn't the URL being generated for this route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

So, I'm working on a Meteor project and I can't get this route to generate properly, or at all for that matter.

```
<template name="browseAll">
    <h3>List of classes with books available!</h3>
    <ul>
        {{#each aggCount}}
            <li><a href="{{ pathFor 'browse-class' }}">{{ _id }}</a> ({{ count }})</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

The data that is being iterated over is a result of aggregation using MongoInternals, and that is as follows:

(server/methods.js excerpt):

```
classCount: function() {

    // Attempt aggregation of the books table to count by class, maybe.
    var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;
    var col = db.collection("books");
    var aggregateSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(col.aggregate.bind(col));
    var pipeline = [
        {$group: {_id: "$class", count: {$sum: 1}}},
        {$sort: {_id: 1}}
    ];
    var theAnswer = aggregateSync(pipeline);
    return theAnswer;

}
```

It seems that the data is coming through okay, and sample data from aggregation (coming into the template) looks like this:

```
[ { _id: 'ADNR1234', count: 2 }, { _id: 'ARTH1234', count: 1 } ]
```

That's the template code I've got, and this is the route that it's supposed to be working with:

```
this.route('browse-class', {
    path: '/browse/:_class',
    data: function() {
        var booksCursor = Books.find({"class": this.params._class},{sort:{"createdAt": 1}});
        return {
            theClass: this.params._class,
            numBooks: booksCursor.count(),
            books: booksCursor
        };
    }
});
```

I don't understand it.  The data is being SHOWN, and what I want to do is generate a URL for `browse-class` (route) that takes the value of `{{ _id }}` in the helper as a parameter, so as to generate something like this:

`application.org/browse/CLSS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `{{pathFor}}` must be called with a data context properly set :

```
{{#with class}}
  {{pathFor "browse-class"}}
{{/with}}
```

Optionnaly it is possible to pass the data context as a parameter :

```
{{pathFor "browse-class" class}}
```

The data context provided to pathFor is used when generating the route path, if you defined a route path like this :

```
path: "/browse/:_id"
```

Then it will use the `_id` from the class to properly generate a URL.

For the text of the link, I doubt you want to display the `_id`, your class documents probably include a "label" so you could use this :

```
<a href="{{ pathFor 'browse-class' }}">{{ label }}</a>
```

Comment: I see.  This is inside an #each block, rather than #with.  Can I still do it the same way?  I've tried using {{pathFor 'browse-class' _id}} and it's not working.  I'm so frustrated.

Comment: In your route definition, specify the path like this : "/browse/:_id" and use {{pathFor "browse-class"}} in the #each loop. I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I think I may have failed to mention that the data this is using is coming from an aggregation of a Books collection.  I will edit my question to include that as well.

Comment: I have made edits to my question that include sample data coming into the template from aggregation, as well as the aggregation code itself.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `_class` by `_id` in your route definition ? Normally that should do the trick.

Comment: I don't know why I never tried that.  Fixed it right up!  Thanks so much.  I'll definitely select this answer, because coupled with these comments you saved my life.  Thanks a ton.